# How do I resolve these two conflicting MVC routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here are the URL's that I'm trying to map with MVC3

```
routes.MapRoute( "Products", "{controller}/{id}/{*name}", new { action = "view" }, new { id = @"\d+" } );
```

> /products/13/seo-friendly-name-of-the-product

Now the next route I need to map is this

```
routes.MapRoute( "General", "{controller}/{id}/{action}", new { }, new { id = @"\d+" } );
```

> /user/42/changepassword

I want to know how to resolve this problem. Simply changing the order isn't enough because one area of the app stops working. I know that {*name} and {action} are being conflicted, but I don't know what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal is to eliminate ambiguous matches, so let's look at making one more specific. Is the controller for your Products route always "Products"? If so, could you change that route to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Products", // Route name
    "products/{id}/{*name}", // URL with parameters
    new { action = "view", controller="Products" }, // defaults
    new { id = @"\d+" } // constraints
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This conflict is difficult to resolve simply because:

```
/products/13/seo-friendly-name-of-the-product
/user/42/changepassword
```

are the same and it will always be the first route that will pick the request. You might need to put some constraints (like for example saying that the catch-all value will always contain dashes which would disambiguate it from the other route because an action name cannot contain dashes or fix the controller for the catch-all route).